# Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to create a rest oauth secured service using spring boot 2.0.0.M4. I am keep getting below exception. I read couple of posts related to error in creating bean with name [...] but nothing worked out.I am posting here my pom.xml along with code. Please guide me if anything clicks to anybody.

---

```
POM.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ctl.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>OauthSpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>OauthSpringBoot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
         <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.6</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>    
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

---

```
OauthSpringBootApplication.java

package ctl.spring.OauthSpringBoot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("ctl.spring")
public class OauthSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OauthSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
EaseRestController .java

package ctl.spring.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import ctl.spring.model.User;
import ctl.spring.services.UserService;


@RestController
public class EaseRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getHello()
    {
        return "Hello World !!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity<List<User>>  getAllUsers()
    {
        List<User> users =userService.findAllUsers();

        if(users ==null || users.size()<0)
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users,HttpStatus.OK); 
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> findUser(@PathVariable String id)
       {
           User data=userService.findUserById(Integer.parseInt(id));

           if(data== null)
               return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
           else
               return new ResponseEntity<User>(data,HttpStatus.OK);
       }

      @RequestMapping(value="/createUser/", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user)
        {
            User dUser= userService.findUserById(Integer.parseInt(user.getId()));

            if(dUser== null) {
            userService.saveUser(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }
            else
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }
        }


}
```

---

```
AuthorizationServer

package ctl.spring.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM+"/client");
    }

}
```

---

```
ResourceServer

package ctl.spring.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http        
        .anonymous()
        .disable()
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/users/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

---

```
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

package ctl.spring.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

---

```
SecurityInitializer

package ctl.spring.security;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

---

```
MethodSecurityConfig

package ctl.spring.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

Along with these I have setup `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` to add `CORSFilter`.

Comment: You existing example is rather complex and unnecessarily difficult for someone to look at closely and run. I would recommend providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: I am using oauth so provided code to build a authorization server, resource server , implementation classes for methodsecurityConfig and websecurityConfigurerAdapter and AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer. I too had created a rest controller where it's runnning fiine without adding security servers but causing issues when I add security classes to my project. I presume that its minimal and complete that can help you to replicate the issue. Please assist.

Comment: I figured out that I have created MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration, where I have autowired,
@Autowired
 private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;
If I comment this than services are up and I can get all tokens and consume the services with tokens and without tokens as well(that's weird) But, If I try auto wiring than I am getting requestHandlerMapping error. Please assist. above has complete code.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by removing below line. I figured out that OAuth2SecurityConfiguration  bean isn't automatically created by boot and neither it is mandatory for MethodSecurityConfigurer. Removing below line and re building the project worked for me like a charm.

```
@Autowired 
private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;
```

Comment: i guess you are referencing the websystique. i got got it working by removing the above code as you said.