# Unit testing - Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, applicationcontext, unmappedresourcehandler

I have a simple TestNG (Same result with JUnit) `@Test` under class as below

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Config.class })
@ActiveProfiles({ "dev" })
public class TestDAO extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

It started failing after merging several code branches.

The error is general/with unspecified origin

```
[main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@33065d67] to prepare test instance [com.TestDAO]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:169)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:450)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$825de2bf.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$31(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$825de2bf$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$14c639e2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$825de2bf.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

It seems that the context is loaded twice, where should I found the issue?

It's not related to [OAuth2SecurityConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548056/error-creating-bean-with-name-resourcehandlermapping-defined-in-class-path-res)  as other answer refer to

> OAuth2SecurityConfiguration bean isn't automatically created by boot and neither it is mandatory for MethodSecurityConfigurer

And not related to [RoleHierarchy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7699)

> Comment out “expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);”, exception disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the spring context includes web related configuration, you need to put 
`@WebAppConfiguration` above your test case. 
Additionally, it seems you need `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` in the case of JUnit runner. So I would change your code as this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Config.class })
@ActiveProfiles({ "dev" })
public class TestDAO extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

Comment: Do you know what trigger the need for `@WebAppConfiguration` in existing tests?

Comment: If you have some web-scoped beans in the spring configuration, Spring JUnit runner needs to initialize a servlet context so then it can create and initialize the Spring context to test.